# Element is not interactable due to dynamic id using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new in selenium. I am facing problem while selecting checkbox but my script returns `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: element has zero size` I only have 1 class attribute in HTML to identify the checkbox element.

I tried using XPath - `//label[@class='k-checkbox-label k-no-text']` but 5 checkbox elements are found. I am able to find the checkbox element when I hover my mouse on :: before

Below is the details:

[image: HTML]

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 3377
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1678533192.649][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 111.
[1678533192.656][WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
Mar 11, 2023 4:43:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 111, so returning the closest version found: 110
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: element has zero size
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [4b1fabc44ae8e1e79c8e00d32813d494, clickElement {id=15a5a2eb-1f11-4702-8a33-d3d83624cd1f}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 111.0.5563.64, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8e..., userDataDir: C:\Users\MKUCHE~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51423}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:51423/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 111.0.5563.64, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (4b1fabc44ae8e1e79c8e00d32813d494)] -> xpath: //label[@class='k-checkbox-label k-no-text'][position()=1]]
Session ID: 4b1fabc44ae8e1e79c8e00d32813d494
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
    at Demo.TestPage.main(TestPage.java:57)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, Your Element is present at the first instance out of other 5 elements, You can change your Xpath as below to click the first occurrence of that element

```
(//label[@class='k-checkbox-label k-no-text'])[1]
```

Note that I have closed your Xpath with open and close brackets, and given the integer '1' inside square brackets, which means the driver will find the first occurrence of that element.